# Full-page ads randomly pop up in Chrome ("Sponsored by")

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware

Sometimes I get this odd behavior while using Google Chrome:

[image: error on Chrome]

It appears only sometimes; I can usually get rid of it by refreshing. Is this from some extension? Should I suspect malware? What should I do to figure out what's injecting this stuff?

Also, subjectively speaking, Chrome's felt much slower lately.

edit: there is a rogue extension ([source](https://blog.ecapuano.com/when-browser-extensions-go-rogue/)). I will debug.

update: it was JQuery Injector, which has now been removed from the Chrome store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a [relatively well-understood problem with some extensions.](https://blog.ecapuano.com/when-browser-extensions-go-rogue/) I'll go in and debug extensions one by one or just redo Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the possibilities for ads getting popped up:

1. Extension: As you mentioned, yes! Extensions do result in popping up of such ads. type `chrome://extensions` in the address bar, and delete all the extensions which you think you didn't install.
2. Toolbar: Sometimes some random toolbar gets install or we install it thinking it is from trusted sources. Some of these toolbars do pop up ads, which are annoying. These toolbars usually get installed in the form of softwares. Check your programs list and uninstall the one which you think you didn't install and is causing this.
3. Website based ads: In this case, the ads are shown by the websites themselves and they can't be avoided unless you're using an ad-blocker. If you're getting these ads only on some particular websites, try using an ad-blocker.
4. In case all the above possibilities fail, then there are chances of some malware, which has many possibilities of getting into.

Try all above methods and see which one helps. Good luck! :)

Comment: I am sure that the ads are website-agnostic. They even appear on websites I previously knew to have no ads. Furthermore, it appears that the content of the "ad" is actually getting blocked by a blocker.

Comment: Did you check all your extensions? It seems from the screenshot that you've installed so many extensions. Do check them once.

Comment: Second to Sankalp's comments. Ads showing on sites that shouldn't have them is a sure sign you've hobbled Chrome with bad extensions, or that malware has re-written your settings. If you're stuck, look for the option in the settings menu to reset Chrome.

Comment: I think removing extensions will simply solve the problem instead of resetting chrome @seagull because if you reset and again log in to chrome using your Google account, the extensions will get installed again.