# How do I find which extension is modifying my website?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, google-chrome-devtools, malware-detection

So, I noticed some other posts related to this (such as [Full-page ads randomly pop up in Chrome ("Sponsored by")](https://superuser.com/questions/1147940/full-page-ads-randomly-pop-up-in-chrome-sponsored-by)); however, since I have an extension that is only injecting an ad once in every 500 or so URLs, I want to know WHICH extension is causing this.

The issue is that every (random) hundred or so URLs I hit (including pages I've written myself) present an ad and create an iframe for my content.  NOT OK!

However, short of process of elimination, is there a way (through DevTools or something) to see which extensions are firing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In Google Chrome, you can disable each extension one at a time and determine what extension is causing the issue.

Comment: Yes, that's the trial-and error method (which I don't want to use, if possible) since - given the low frequency of injections, I will have to run without extensions for a long period of time to find it.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Chrome has an extension activity logging mode which I think can only be accessed via a command line.

Comment: Windows 10 Build 17134

Comment: I don't know if extension activity logging will help you, but if you'd like to use it, you can enable it with the [instructions on this page](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/02/23/google-chrome-activity-log-for-extensions/). The instructions in the article are for Chrome Canary, but the article is about 4 months old, so I am assuming it is available on the current stable release of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the delay on this, but answering my own question, I found that it was not an extension, but my ISP was injecting HTML on port 80 (never happened under SSL). (BEWARE OPTIMUM USERS: in some markets, they are injecting HTML ads when you request a site). I confirmed this with Optimum and they stated that it does not violate their policies (however, they have since shut it off in my area).